# Raspbian - systemd user instance not working

Tags: linux, user-accounts, systemd, raspbian

I'm setting up a small server on a RaspberryPi 3 and added a new user ('server') for a rootless docker instance.
But I'm facing the problem, that i do not get the user instance of systemd working. It fails with the following errors:

```
systemctl --user status :
   Failed to connect to bus: no permission
systemd --user --test :
   [...] failed to open directory /home/pi/.config [...]
systemd --user :
   Failed to create /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope/init.scope control group: Permission denied
   Failed to allocate manager object: Permission denied
```

As you can see, the user 'pi' is mentioned in one of the errors, even if I'm logged in (via su) as 'server'.

So my question is: how to get systemd working properly so that I can setup docker?

uname -a: Linux Pi-Server 5.10.17-v7+ #1421 SMP Thu May 27 13:59:01 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux 
command to create user: sudo useradd -m -d /home/server server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much trickier than you thought.

First of all, `su` does not really "log you in" as another user. Even when you use `-`, it still only `Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login`. If you for example run `loginctl`, you will not see a session being created when you `su`.

With that said, what you would like to achieve is possible. You can run `loginctl enable-linger server` to make the user instance start upon boot.

Then for `systemctl --user` to work when you `su server`, you will need to set two *environment variables* (and whitelist them if you use `-`):

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u server) DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u server)/bus su server

XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u server) DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u server)/bus su -w XDG_RUNTIME_DIR,DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS - server
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Yan stated, `su` does not create a new session.
His solution is sufficient for my problem but I want to mention an other approach which I found after searching through the Docker documentation:
you should be able to start a new session if you use `ssh server@localhost`.